# How can I add properties to the logs being generated by slonik with roarr?

Tags: slonik, roarr

I would like to add some root level properties to match our CloudWatch format  (with tracing information) to our sql logs so they can be querieable alongside our app logs,

By root level I mean outside the 'context' property, but even adding to context might work for us if there's no alternative.

I researched the slonik repository issues and there are a few (closed with 'will not do') requesting for slonik to allow to 'inject a custom logger' issues that imply that there is a way to do it natively with roarr, or maybe using slonik interceptors, but can't wrap my head around how I could add these properties at run-time.

Using `global.ROARR.prepend` may bring problems with multiple concurrent requests, so I'm not convinced this is the way to do it.

Specifically, and to help to give more context, I need to add 'user id' of the user making request that makes the query, "awsRequestId", "x-correlation-trace-id" and "x-correlation-trace-id" so the loged sql queries are also part of the filtering that we make with tracing information.

Please don't worry about sql queries and potential information leakage on the logs, those concerns are handled for production.